# express-validator email normalization

Tags: node.js, validation, email, express-validator

I am using express-validator 6.9.2 for my Nodejs project. But when I used normalizeEmail() in my auth controller one of my test email "t.test@gmail.com" is stored in dB as "ttest@gmail.com".
When I tried to log in to my app using t.test@gmail.com and ttest@gmail.com I was able to log in successfully. But when trying to create a new user with the email ttest@gmail.com. It shows an error email already exists. How can I normalize my email and store as "t.test@gmail.com" in dB?

Comment: Adding the code to your question will make it stand out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the options that you pass your validator you need to set property `gmail_remove_dots` to false. [Here](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers) is the documentation.

```js
check('email').normalizeEmail({gmail_remove_dots:false})
```